# Images with the final -1

Tags: database, wordpress

Hello I have a problem with my media uploads. When I want to upload the media I've got "**-1**" at the final of name.

This happened always when I want to upload some file in Media, if I rename the file in ftp, in the wordpress I can't see the images of course.

Do you have another solutions to fix this issue?

*Thanks and best regards*

My attempts:

- I tried to clear all cache
- I tried with another browser
- I tried to search in db
- I tried to clean db with a plugin
- I tried to delete all revisions of post and pages
- I tried to deactivate all plugins
- I tried to find the similar file via FTP but anything match with it
- I tried to find duplicate files with a plugin but didn't match anything